# error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char*’ in initialization

Tags: c++, libcurl

i have python script that download exchange rates from web page, and i want make c++ program from that, here is what i have so far:

```
include iostream
include time.h
include stdio.h
include curl/curl.h
include curl/easy.h
include string
define CURL_STATICLIB

using namespace std;

void dat(string &d){
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char datum[80];
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo=localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(datum,80,"%d%m%y",timeinfo);
    d=datum;
}

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}


int main()
{
    string f;
    dat(f);
    string l1="http://www.hnb.hr/tecajn/f";
    string l2=".dat";
    string linkz=l1+f+l2;
    cout << linkz;

    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = linkz;
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "/home/tomi/data.txt";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);


    return 0;
}
```

it give me this error when i try to compile, i found used algorythm for download txt, so i hope it is correct

Comment: Hello, @Tomislav. Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a courtesy to the people answering your question, please **paste** the **exact** code that you are compiling (don't retype it, but copy-paste it). Also paste the exact error message you see. In the case of this program, there are many errors -- it is certainly not precisely the same program you are trying to compile.

Answer (score 6):

If you'd have pointed out the line where you got the error, I wouldn't have had to track it down to:

```
string linkz=l1+f+l2;
...
char *url = linkz;
```

You can use `c_str()` to get a pointer to the const characters in the string. So this will do:

```
char const* url = linkz.c_str();
```

You could have that very same line in the `setopt` call, or have `url` be an `std::string` as well.

Answer (score 6):

`char *url = linkz;` should be `const char* url = linkz.c_str();` assuming you really need a C-style string for API reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line:

```
char *url = linkz;
```

"links" is an std::string, but"url" is a char *. Try using the c_str method of string to get what you need like so:

```
const char * url = links.c_str();
```